# Expo React Native couldn't start project on Android: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Before I update my Expo cli there is no problem when I run React Native project in Android emulator (from Android Studio) I can run it from localhost, but after I updated my expo cli I got this error:

[image: Metro Builder error]

I can't run my project in emulator, but if I connected my phone to my laptop using the hotspot, I can run my project, but I must copy the link from the metro builder to Expo apps. Like this:

[Link from metro builder when I connected to phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnvpN.png)

and I must copy that URL to expo like this to run the project:

[Expo app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YARpm.png)

And my project running, but when I clicked "Run on android device / emulator" it will shows the error in the title.

Before I update to Expo cli v 3.15.4 there is no problem, I can run my project without hotspot, localhost only.

And if run without hotspot, the project doesn't run, it will give me an error.

Comment: Facing the same problem.

Comment: same problem, did you have any results?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. I solved the problem changing the path of my ANDROID_HOME environment variable. It was wrong!!!
Make sure that the path points to your android sdk location, by default the path is something like this:
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

I also updated my "path" system variable adding these two paths:
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms
C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

I hope it solves your problem too. Good luck!

Comment: there's no such a dir like that in AppData. Every answer report this, but the only sdk android studio shows is on win `C:\Android\android-sdk`

Comment: This worked for me, I was missing the ANDROID_HOME environment variable (I had ANDROID_SDK_HOME, but it seems expo uses the former)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to these answers, I found this [post](https://forums.expo.dev/t/couldnt-start-project-on-android-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/35047) which mentions that the checking of "adb" in expo is via this function:

```
function whichADB() {
  if (process.env.ANDROID_HOME) {
    return `${process.env.ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools/adb`;
  }
  return 'adb';
}
```

This really clarifies what needs to be done which are to either:

- Add `ANDROID_HOME` in environment variables with path value of your Sdk installation (commonly in `C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

or

- Append `C:\Users\chual\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` under `Path` in your environment variables. If you choose this method, make sure that you **do not have** incorrectly configured `ANDROID_HOME` in your environment variables because that will take precedence over this.

As a side note, notice that `ANDROID_HOME` only points up to `Sdk` folder while in `Path`, it is upto `platform-tools`.

Comment: changing ANDROID_HOME to C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Roll back your Expo version to the previous version that was working. Sometimes breaking changes go into the release. Unless you upgraded because of a new feature, this is OK. Open an issue on their GitHub so they know about this. Also, double check that you did not reorganise files in your folder or change any paths in the code hence the path error.

Comment: how do i add this issue to their github ? I'm new using github , can u tell me how to open an issue on their github ? thank you so much sir

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to be worried about this if you are using expo. Just open any emulator and install expo on the emulator then copy LAN connection from metro run after this open expo app in emulator just paste that link in clipboard now relax and chill your app is build on emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Also, in my case, I have installed node.js in a different directory(D) and was getting the same error. So all I did was updating my "Path" system variable with the location of the folder where "expo-cli" was installed(C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm) and it worked for me.